# Is that OK to modify a question significantly？

Tags: support, editing, asking-questions

If, after posting a question for some time, I found out it is another related but quite different question that really interested me. Is that OK to just modify the original question to the new one, or it's more preferable to post a new question?

Comment: +1 for asking on meta. We mostly experience people just *doing* this. I appreciate the exercised caution.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I blame the Nike slogan... :-P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there are answers, or even comments, you shouldn't invalidate them by changing your question.

If no one responded to your post at all, perhaps delete the old one and post the new one.

In general it is preferable to post a new question.