# Editing the title/body of a question hours after asking?

Tags: discussion, editing, asking-questions, bumping

I asked a question which received some [comments immediately](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3764653/element-of-vi-is-a-k-algebra-homomorphism-kx-1-x-2-dots-x-n-i-righ). Only after the comments came in did I realize that I should ask my question differently. I edited the question then.

I now realize that the *title* of the question does not in fact reflect what I *actually* want to ask. But it's been around 8 hours since I asked the question. Is it "okay" to fix the title, and thereby bump the question up?

More broadly, what should one do if a question has been asked, but one realizes (hours) later that the question can be rephrased in either title or body to become much clearer?

Comment: One factor to take into account is also whether or not there already are some answers. There are a few related discussions here on meta, such as: [question edited to change meaning](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2304), [Is that OK to modify a question significantly?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20103) or [Editing a question after receiving one or more answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26565).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it needs to be fixed, fix it. You are much better to do this as soon as possible (before people get confused by the ambiguity).

If it's "close enough" that people who actually read the question will know what you mean, and it's not clickbaity, you could reasonably leave it as it is, too.

It's probably better to err for clarity and efficiency, so if you're editing, try to fix any issues in the body and tags too.

It will be bumped so the community can see what happened, and can then alter their votes or comments or answers to account for it.

You are evidently not editing *just because you want the bump*, so this is not an abuse of the system or an unnecessary change.

Comment: Please note @MartinSleziak's comment below the question.  Modifying a question after it has been answered is typically frowned upon.